# Flot pie chart series name "undefined"

Tags: javascript, charts, flot, pie-chart

I am trying to display browser visits for my site using flot pie chart. Everything is working properly except the series name displays as undefined.
Data for the series is.

```
[

    [
        "Chrome",
        "54"
    ],
    [
        "Firefox",
        "51"
    ],
    [
        "Internet Explorer",
        "9"
    ],
    [
        "Opera Mini",
        "2"
    ],
    [
        "Safari",
        "2"
    ]

]
```

and the JavaScript is

```
$('#browserVisits').css({
    height: '300px',
    width: '100%'
});

$.plot($('#browserVisits'), visits, {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    }
});
```

And the result for this series is like
[image: Pie Chart]

Why the series name displays undefined instead of browser name?
What am I doing wrong and what can be the solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well you just have to add formatter function in pie block as follows

```
label: {
                 show: true,
                 formatter: function(label,point){
                     return(point.label + '<br>'+ point.percent.toFixed(2) + '%');

                 }
             }
```

Also i have  created a sample fiddle for you take a look 
http://jsfiddle.net/coolbhushans/03kd2mav/

Comment: I looked at your sample fiddle and modified my data. First it was in array, then i parsed it to JSON object and defined label and data. Then it worked. I didn't need to put formatter. Thanks for the fiddle.